# How to shuffle an array such that unique elements are obtained at all indexes?

Tags: php

I have an array `$myAr=array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7").` I want to create five more arrays by shuffling this array five times using `shuffle($myAr)`.

My requirement is that, all elements at zero index should be unique (i.e. not repeated) in all arrays. Similarly for all indexes.

Comment: Shuffle and compare with existsing values. Shuffle more if required

Answer (score 0):

Define your array without the unique value you want. And use [array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) for add the first value after.

Example :

```
$myAr=array("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7");

$fiveArray = array();

for ($i=0; $i < 5 ; $i++) { 
    shuffle($myAr);
    $fiveArray[$i] = $myAr;
    array_unshift($fiveArray[$i], 1);
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($fiveArray, true), '</pre> <hr/>';
```

Show :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 3
            [5] => 5
            [6] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 7
            [5] => 5
            [6] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 3
            [6] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 5
            [6] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 3
            [5] => 6
            [6] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: This does not remove repetition e.g. [1][1] = [2][1] = 4

Comment: Just change your for loop: 
`$i=0 -> $i = count($myAr) ; $i <= count($myAr)+5 ; $i++; `